# Unexpected behaviour of Process.MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, .net, msdn

I've been trying to understand [Process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx).

According to MSDN; "The main window is the window that is created when the process is started. After initialization, other windows may be opened, including the Modal and TopLevel windows, but *the first window associated with the process remains the main window*." (Emphasis added)

But while debugging I noticed that MainWindowHandle seemed to change value... which I wasn't expecting, especially after consulting the documentation above.

To confirm the behaviour I created a standalone WinForms app with a timer to check the MainWindowHandle of the "DEVENV" (Visual Studio) process every 100ms.

Here's the interesting part of this test app...

```
    IntPtr oldHWnd = IntPtr.Zero;

    void GetMainwindowHandle()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("DEVENV");

        if (processes.Length!=1)
            return;

        IntPtr newHWnd = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;

        if (newHWnd != oldHWnd)
        {
            oldHWnd = newHWnd;
            textBox1.AppendText(processes[0].MainWindowHandle.ToString("X")+"\r\n");
        }

    }

    private void timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetMainwindowHandle();
    }
```

You can see the value of MainWindowHandle changing when you (for example) click on a drop-down menu inside VS.

[image: MainWindowHandleMystery]

Perhaps I've misunderstood the documentation.

Can anyone shed light?

Comment: I have lost 10 hours because of this bug. Thanks MS!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@edg,

I guess it's an error in MSDN. You can clearly see in Relfector, that "Main window" check in .NET looks like:

```
private bool IsMainWindow(IntPtr handle)
{
    return (!(NativeMethods.GetWindow(new HandleRef(this, handle), 4) != IntPtr.Zero)  
             && NativeMethods.IsWindowVisible(new HandleRef(this, handle)));
}
```

When .NET code enumerates windows, it's pretty obvious that first visible window (i.e. top level window) will match this criteria.

Answer (score 5):

Actually Process.MainWindowHandle is a handle of top-most window, it's not really the "Main Window Handle"