# Set window.owner from Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle

Tags: wpf, winforms, mainwindow

I am in a Win Form application, somewhere in a document I need to call this dialog written in wpf and I want to set the window.owner.  The only thing close I found to get the main window of my application is the following.

I want to set the Window.Owner with a Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, but have no idea how to cast the window handle into a window.

Answer (score 4):

The [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) class allows you to set the owner of a WPF Window using an HWND (as an `IntPtr`).

In your case, it should be:

```
WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(theWpfWindow);
wih.Owner = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

theWpfWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why is it so hard to find these kind of details.  I have been looking on the web for hours, I could not find anything.

Comment: @Jean-MarcD. It helps if you know where to look - The interop site is a good resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742474.aspx

Comment: `MainWindowHandle` is not reliable. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/48288/200443 If there is a popup open, `MainWindowHandle` will return the handle of this popup instead of the real "MainWindow"