# Process.MainWindowHandle returns IntPtr.Zero when Tooltips are hovered

Tags: c#, .net, process, f#, user32

I have a simple function which works about like this:

```ml
let possibleParents:Seq<Process> = GetProcessesByExecutableFileName(exeName)
let el = match possibleParents with
            | x when x.Where(fun y -> y.MainWindowHandle > IntPtr.Zero).Count() = 1 -> AutomationElement.FromHandle <| Seq.head possibleParents // Only works if no tooltips or menus are open
            | x when x.Where(fun y -> y.MainWindowHandle > IntPtr.Zero).Count() < 1 -> AutomationElement.FromHandle <| Win32.FindWindowByProcess exeName //ALWAYS works
            | x when x.Count() > 1 -> AutomationElement.RootElement // start search from Desktop
            | _ -> null
```

So, when the getting the Process object from .NET, it returns IntPtr.Zero if there are any menus\contextmenus, tooltips or comboboxes open. As soon as you move your mouse away from a tooltip, it returns a real IntPtr value.

Why is this? I can understand mdi children & other window hierarchy causing this, but not simply mousing over a tooltip. What does user32.dll imports do to find the Handle that the Process class does differently?

Answers in F#, C# or VB.NET welcome.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288/unexpected-behaviour-of-process-mainwindowhandle) indicates that `.MainWindowHandle` just returns the top most window, maybe the tooltip is causing it to return zero? And also that post is 8 years old so it may be very outdated by now..